# regarding awk field delimiter

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Want to get the decimal part of the first field from the du -h  command.  So the field delimiter should be the character K or character M. I tried multiple options with -F and it was not working.

```
du -h AWSD.????.20121123.????.LBB4.????.*.gz  |
    tr -s ' ' | 
    awk -F'K|M' 'BEGIN{x=0;} {print $1;} END{print x;}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? What is your expected output?

Comment: I just want the unit part of the first field of the du -h.  I want to do the sum of total usage using awk.

Comment: Post the output of your du command and the desired output of your awk command so everyone can stop guessing.

Comment: The output is only blank lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be looking for an awk solution that will use either `K` or `M` as the field delimiter.  Your solution was almost correct and will work if you enclose `KM` as a character class:

```
du -h | awk -F '[KM]' '{ print $1 }'
```

Now, in the original question, you also wanted to total usage.  In that case, it's not correct to drop the `K` or `M` character - it's better in this case to use `df -k` and just sum column 1:

```
$ du -k | awk '{ sum+=$1 } END { print sum, "k" }'
52939620 k
$ du -k | awk '{ sum+=$1*1024 } END { print sum/1e6, "x 1e6 bytes" }' 
54210.2 x 1e6 bytes
$ du -k | awk '{ sum+=$1*1024 } END { print sum/1e9, "x 1e9 bytes" }'
54.2102 x 1e9 bytes
```

Note how this code avoids the discussion about MebiBytes vs MegaBytes.

Note2: This code, however, counts child directories once again for each parent directory.
On a Solaris system, add `-o` to `du -k` to prevent this.

Comment: I tried the below one. It's not working.  Running in solaris 10.  I tried with a space and without a space after the F delimiter both are not working.    du -h AWSD.????.20121123.????.LBB4.????.*.gz    | tr -s ' ' |  awk -F'[KM]' '{ print $1; }'

Comment: On Solaris, use `nawk` instead of `awk`.  Also see see the note about `du -ko`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is either the first field:

```
du -h AWSD.????.20121123.????.LBB4.????.*.gz | cut -f1
```

Or first field without the unit:

```
du -h AWSD.????.20121123.????.LBB4.????.*.gz | cut -f1 | sed 's/[GMK]$//'
```

Or to get the integer part of the first field:

```
du -h AWSD.????.20121123.????.LBB4.????.*.gz | sed 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do i use pattern matching to skip K or M in the field delimiter of awk.

Comment: The below one produces empty output.du -h AWSD.????.20121123.????.LBB4.????.*.gz | sed 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'

Comment: are you including the escapes (backslashes) in: `sed 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'`?

Comment: Tried with the escapes (backslashes) blank line gets printed continously,  I just copied the command that you posted and ran it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is to use built-in type conversion (nawk/gawk):

```
du -h | nawk '{print $1+0}'
```

The field is converted to a numeric type by adding zero, trailing characters which are not part of a number are simply ignored. (Though you should understand what is accepted as numeric, e.g. input like "123e10" will be treated as 123x10^10 .)

A disadvantage of using FS for this is that the only way to recover which separator was present is to inspect $0. Something like:

```
if ( match($1,/([0-9.]+)([KMGT])/,bb) ) {
  ...
}
```

would be my suggestion (gawk >=3.1.0).

If you are dealing with large numbers, you may need to use printf(), or modify the default numeric output format (OFMT variable), rather than just "print".
I have long since given up parsing platform-dependent output of ls/df/du etc, using GNU stat (coreutils) is more robust in my experience.